# Controversy of R_LIBS_USER path

Tags: r

When I check the R environment I got:

```
> Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")
[1] "~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3"
```

But when I `cd` to the directory, there seems no this path at all:

```
dz33@ccis4240:~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library$ ll -a
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 dz33 dz33 4096 Jul  2  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 dz33 dz33 4096 Jul 10  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x 64 dz33 dz33 4096 Mar 30 16:41 3.2
```

As you can see there is only `/3.2` directory but `/3.3`. Does anybody know why and How to change to `3.2` or set up `3.3`? It appears my R version is the latest:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "linux-gnu"

$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "3.0"

$year
[1] "2016"

$month
[1] "05"

$day
[1] "03"

$`svn rev`
[1] "70573"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)"

$nickname
[1] "Supposedly Educational"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the R\_LIBS\_USER variable so that R appends the version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472835/how-do-i-set-the-r-libs-user-variable-so-that-r-appends-the-version-number)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `R_LIBS_USER` variable is *optional* and, if set, will be prepended to the library path (which is displayed by `.libPaths()`).

I may be in the minority but on the systems I look after I try to *unset* `R_LIBS_USER` so that I get

```
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"  
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"           
R>
```

meaning that `install.packages()` *et al* will use a *system-wide* directory accessible by all users on the system --- which makes sense at work where we have multi-user systems.  One thing to note is that you want your users to be members of a group with group-write permissions on that directory to be able to install (as long as you can trust your users).

Doing it this also does away with *versioned* directories (ie `3.2/` vs `3.3/`) you observed.

Fuller details are in `help(Startup)`.

Comment: Interesting policy on R, enforcing newest versions for all. (I don't disagree.) Do you find people need to use strategies like `checkpoint` to ensure they don't unknowingly upgrade versions? (Also, if the `/usr/local/...` path is not using versioned directories is it compatible on R upgrades, say from 3.2 to 3.3?)

Comment: Thanks, @Dirk! The reason I was asking that is because there was an error when I was trying to install a package locally: `R CMD INSTALL vimcom_0.9-93.tar.gz `  `Error in library(vimcom) : there is no package called ‘vimcom’`, but a `vimcom_0.9-93.tar.gz` is in the dir physically.

Comment: "Enforcing" ?  How about "offering" ?   I am not a fan of checkpoint, packrat and what not.  I have had good luck for 10+ years with R by relying on packages with sensible maintainers who do not break their APIs.

Comment: Suddenly, my R no longer picks up R_LIBS_USER any more, any one knows how to fix this problem.  I has local installed packages in R_LIBS_USER. After staring R, .libPaths() does not include the $R_LIBS_USER directory.  Used to include it. Not sure what change caused this. Now I cannot even load the packages. I can manually add this path from inside R, but I need to to be flexible in managing the R environment outside R.

Comment: regarding the [versioned directories] caveat: from the manual {Both R_LIBS_USER and R_LIBS_SITE feature possible expansion of specifiers for R-version-specific information as part of the startup process. The possible conversion specifiers all start with a ‘⁠%⁠’ and are followed by a single letter (use ‘⁠%%⁠’ to obtain ‘⁠%⁠’)}