# How do I set the R_LIBS_USER variable so that R appends the version number?

Tags: r

By default (in Windows), R saves libraries to a path that is something like:

```
C:\Users\(username)\R\3.3
```

I would like to change the `C:\Users\(username)` part of that, but still allow R to assign the `R\3.3` part.  I.e., when I update R, it should start using `R\3.4`, etc..

You can change the entire install path by setting the environment variable `R_LIBS_USER`.  Is there an environment variable for just the prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pattern `%v` in the value of `R_LIBS_USER`. This is documented in the [`libPaths` documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html).

Note that this only works if the path actually exists: `.libPaths` will ignore nonexistent paths.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure directory exist...

then in your Renviron file edit/(or add) following -

```
R_LIBS_USER=C:\Users\(username)\%v
```

for patterns, refer below:

`
‘⁠%V⁠’

```
R version number including the patchlevel (e.g., ‘⁠4.2.1’).
```

‘⁠%v⁠’

```
R version number excluding the patchlevel (e.g., ‘⁠4.2’).
```

‘⁠%p⁠’

```
the platform for which R was built, the value of R.version$platform.
```

‘⁠%o⁠’

```
the underlying operating system, the value of R.version$os.
```

‘⁠%a⁠’

```
the architecture (CPU) R was built on/for, the value of R.version$arch.
```

`